# Delete specific command history and current "command" history that just recently typed

Tags: linux, centos, history

How to delete a specific command history and when you enter that "command" that will delete the specific command?

For example, here is my history:

```
1 ls -l
2 cat > foo.txt
3 ifconfig
4 echo "Hello"
```

Now, I want to delete the `ifconfig` command history which is **Number: 3**, so I'll do the following command: `history -d 3` ( which will delete the ifconfig command).

The second one is, I want to delete that command I recently typed `(history -d 3)` or in other words, this command will not be remembered in history, so no one can see that I just deleted a specific command history.

To summarize, the `ifconfig` command history will be deleted and the recently type `history -d 3` command will not be remembered/logged in history.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly what you are looking for but maybe still a possible/usefull workaround.

You can setup your history to ignore Commands which have a space as first character.
You can add this functionallity by adding the following line to your `.bashrc`

```
HISTCONTROL=ignorespace
```